# Third party libs to Convert HTML/XAML for Windows 8 Metro App?

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight

Third party libs to Convert HTML/XAML for Windows 8 Metro App ?
I using C#,Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8, Windows 8 Release Preview 
I want to convert html file to xaml,but I can't find third-party-libs to Convert HTML/XAML support Metro App , any ideas ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can create a Metro application using Javascript. You have to check project template

here's the link for creating your first HTML and JAvascript MEtro application
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986964.aspx

Comment: thank you ! My project is GridApp use Silverlight and just RickTextBlock need binding HTMl file ,any idea ?